# Создание SQL триггера для своего проекта

Tags: c#, sql

Есть проект на C# WPF, к нему подключена БД на SQL Server. Необходимо создать событие добавления записи к БД извне. Я понял, что для этого пишут Триггеры CLR на C#. Но для этого они создают отдельный проект для написания триггеров `Проект базы данных SQL CLR`, а как можно написать встроенный триггер в мою программу? Или же уже существует готовое решение в библиотеках?

Или же, как вариант, сделать таймер, там создать постоянное соединение с БД и ежесекундно проверять, изменилось ли количество элементов в таблице или нет.

Задача : у меня есть приложение WPF, оно должно получать новые данные из БД. Соответственно, получать эти данные оно должно только после того, как новые данные загружены в БД. Таким образом, необходимо создать событие, которое будет реагировать на добавление данных на SQL Server.

Comment: Триггеры работают внутри БД без обращения к внешним приложениям.  Обычно пишутся на строенном языке. при желании можно написать на C# но они должны находится и запускаться внутри самой БД, поэтому и требование собирать их отдельно. Для общения с внешними приложениями есть другие методы. Опишите задачу, для чего именно это понадобилось

Comment: @Mike добавил информацию в основной пост.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28038648/can-sql-server-push-a-message-to-a-program

Comment: @Mike о, спасибо большое, я уверен был, что такое есть в стандартных библиотеках, но не знал, что именно взять.

Answer (score -1):

Я не понял сути вопроса. Вам надо создать нечто, делающее новую запись в БД или нечто, реагирующее на добавление записи в БД?

В последнем случае применимы триггеры в БД:
http://datasql.ru/basesql/14.htm

Comment: Добавил информацию в основной пост.